# find xml block and replace all, regex to match and call back to overwrite

Tags: php, regex

I need to just do a quick match and replace all that comes from a xml.  I don't want to phrase the file since the file is like 100mb and I can't stop that from being the case.  So here is the sample data.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <products>
        <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
            <sku>SKUTARGET</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[agag adgsgsdg asdgsdg]]></description>
            <keywords></keywords>
            <price>9.000000</price>
            <stock_quantity>35</stock_quantity>
            <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <length>0.000000</length>
            <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
            <weight>0.000000</weight>
            <color>Black</color>
            <material>PVC</material>
            <barcode>883045010070</barcode>
            <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
            <images>
                <image>/sdssd/sdfsd.jpg</image>
                <image>/AL10sdfsds07XO/sdfsd.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <categories>
                <category code="166" video="0" parent="172">sd &amp; Sexy sdf</category>
                <category code="172" video="0" parent="">sd &amp; dddsdsds</category>
                <category code="641" video="0" parent="172">sdfsdf Costume sdfsdfsdf</category>
            </categories>
            <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">sdfsdf sdfs</manufacturer>
            <type code="LI" video="0">sdfsd</type>
        </product>
        <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
            <sku>XXXXXXX</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[LEATHER sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[asdgsdgsd sad sadg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg]]></description>
            <keywords></keywords>
            <price>5.000000</price>
            <stock_quantity>36</stock_quantity>
            <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <length>0.000000</length>
            <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
            <weight>0.000000</weight>
            <color>Black</color>
            <material>Leather</material>
            <barcode>883045300164</barcode>
            <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
            <images>
                <image>/AL10sds0XO/sdsdsd.jpg</image>
                <image>/sdsds/AL1sd00XOB.jpg</image>
                <image>/AL1sdsds00XO/sdsds.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <categories>
                <category code="80" video="0" parent="44">sdgsdgsdg</category>
                <category code="181" video="0" parent="172">Sleep &amp; Lounge</category>
            </categories>
            <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">Allure sdsds</manufacturer>
            <type code="LI" video="0">sdsfsdfsd</type>
        </product>
    </products>
```

What I need is just the one block starting at node products where the sku is a var in this case "SKUTARGET"

```
        <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
            <sku>SKUTARGET</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[agag adgsgsdg asdgsdg]]></description>
            <keywords></keywords>
            <price>9.000000</price>
            <stock_quantity>35</stock_quantity>
            <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <length>0.000000</length>
            <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
            <weight>0.000000</weight>
            <color>Black</color>
            <material>PVC</material>
            <barcode>883045010070</barcode>
            <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
            <images>
                <image>/sdssd/sdfsd.jpg</image>
                <image>/AL10sdfsds07XO/sdfsd.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <categories>
                <category code="166" video="0" parent="172">sd &amp; Sexy sdf</category>
                <category code="172" video="0" parent="">sd &amp; dddsdsds</category>
                <category code="641" video="0" parent="172">sdfsdf Costume sdfsdfsdf</category>
            </categories>
            <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">sdfsdf sdfs</manufacturer>
            <type code="LI" video="0">sdfsd</type>
        </product>
```

Here is the code I'm working with at the moment

```
    <?php

    ob_start();
    ?> 
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <products>
        <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
            <sku>SKUTARGET</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[agag adgsgsdg asdgsdg]]></description>
            <keywords></keywords>
            <price>9.000000</price>
            <stock_quantity>35</stock_quantity>
            <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <length>0.000000</length>
            <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
            <weight>0.000000</weight>
            <color>Black</color>
            <material>PVC</material>
            <barcode>883045010070</barcode>
            <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
            <images>
                <image>/sdssd/sdfsd.jpg</image>
                <image>/AL10sdfsds07XO/sdfsd.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <categories>
                <category code="166" video="0" parent="172">sd &amp; Sexy sdf</category>
                <category code="172" video="0" parent="">sd &amp; dddsdsds</category>
                <category code="641" video="0" parent="172">sdfsdf Costume sdfsdfsdf</category>
            </categories>
            <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">sdfsdf sdfs</manufacturer>
            <type code="LI" video="0">sdfsd</type>
        </product>
        <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
            <sku>XXXXXXX</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[LEATHER sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[asdgsdgsd sad sadg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg]]></description>
            <keywords></keywords>
            <price>5.000000</price>
            <stock_quantity>36</stock_quantity>
            <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <length>0.000000</length>
            <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
            <weight>0.000000</weight>
            <color>Black</color>
            <material>Leather</material>
            <barcode>883045300164</barcode>
            <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
            <images>
                <image>/AL10sds0XO/sdsdsd.jpg</image>
                <image>/sdsds/AL1sd00XOB.jpg</image>
                <image>/AL1sdsds00XO/sdsds.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <categories>
                <category code="80" video="0" parent="44">sdgsdgsdg</category>
                <category code="181" video="0" parent="172">Sleep &amp; Lounge</category>
            </categories>
            <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">Allure sdsds</manufacturer>
            <type code="LI" video="0">sdsfsdfsd</type>
        </product>
    </products>

    <?php

    $xml_str = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $tar_sku="SKUTARGET"; // this is the sku of the product block I need to have
    $pat= '/^.*(<product *<sku>'.$tar_sku.'</sku>*</product>).*$/is'; // this should match the block with the sku but no other block

    $replacement='$1';//This should overwrite everything with that found block.

    $returnValue = preg_replace($pat, $replacement, $xml_str);
```

Any help would be great.  Thanks.
Jeremy

**[edit]**

Here is the test code from the suggestion below.  As of yet don'ts work.  I was expecting to echo back that string of the xml  block with that sku matching.  no luck yet.

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    umask(0);

    $xml_str = <<<EOD
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <products>
                <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
                    <sku>SKUTARGET</sku>
                    <name><![CDATA[sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
                    <description><![CDATA[agag adgsgsdg asdgsdg]]></description>
                    <keywords></keywords>
                    <price>9.000000</price>
                    <stock_quantity>35</stock_quantity>
                    <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
                    <height>0.000000</height>
                    <length>0.000000</length>
                    <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
                    <weight>0.000000</weight>
                    <color>Black</color>
                    <material>PVC</material>
                    <barcode>883045010070</barcode>
                    <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
                    <images>
                        <image>/sdssd/sdfsd.jpg</image>
                        <image>/AL10sdfsds07XO/sdfsd.jpg</image>
                    </images>
                    <categories>
                        <category code="166" video="0" parent="172">sd &amp; Sexy sdf</category>
                        <category code="172" video="0" parent="">sd &amp; dddsdsds</category>
                        <category code="641" video="0" parent="172">sdfsdf Costume sdfsdfsdf</category>
                    </categories>
                    <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">sdfsdf sdfs</manufacturer>
                    <type code="LI" video="0">sdfsd</type>
                </product>
                <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
                    <sku>XXXXXXX</sku>
                    <name><![CDATA[LEATHER sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
                    <description><![CDATA[asdgsdgsd sad sadg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg]]></description>
                    <keywords></keywords>
                    <price>5.000000</price>
                    <stock_quantity>36</stock_quantity>
                    <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
                    <height>0.000000</height>
                    <length>0.000000</length>
                    <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
                    <weight>0.000000</weight>
                    <color>Black</color>
                    <material>Leather</material>
                    <barcode>883045300164</barcode>
                    <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
                    <images>
                        <image>/AL10sds0XO/sdsdsd.jpg</image>
                        <image>/sdsds/AL1sd00XOB.jpg</image>
                        <image>/AL1sdsds00XO/sdsds.jpg</image>
                    </images>
                    <categories>
                        <category code="80" video="0" parent="44">sdgsdgsdg</category>
                        <category code="181" video="0" parent="172">Sleep &amp; Lounge</category>
                    </categories>
                    <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">Allure sdsds</manufacturer>
                    <type code="LI" video="0">sdsfsdfsd</type>
                </product>
            </products>


    EOD;


    $tar_sku="SKUTARGET"; // this is the sku of the product block I need to have
    $pattern = "~<product .*?<sku>$tar_sku</sku>.*?</product>~is"; 
    $returnValue = preg_match($pattern,$xml_str);

    echo '--'.$returnValue[0];
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not use a regex to parse XML.** If your concern is memory usage, using a regex will consume *much more memory* than incremental parsing. Since a regex can only operate on a string, you will need at least 100MB of memory just to hold the file string before you can do anything with it. If you use an incremental XML parser, you can use less memory than the size of the file.

The right tool for this job is [`XMLReader`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).

### tl;dr

There are two `XMLReader` parsing implementations in this answer:

- `getmatchingproducts_xml_expand()` or `getmatchingproducts_xml_noexpand()` functions returns a list of all matched products. Memory usage depends on how many matching SKU products are in the source xml.
- `ProductMatcher` class is an Iterator (can be used in `foreach`) that will return matched products incrementally as either a string, `DOMDocument`, or `SimpleXMLElement`. It uses about 1MB of memory no matter how big your source XML is or how many products match.

### Test File

I created a 120 MB sample file using the format you created. This is the creation code:

```
function maketestfile() {
    $xml = <<<EOT
        <product active="1" on_sale="0" discountable="0">
            <sku>{{SKU}}</sku>
            <name><![CDATA[LEATHER sdfsdf (NET)]]></name>
            <description><![CDATA[asdgsdgsd sad sadg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg asdg]]></description>
            <keywords></keywords>
            <price>5.000000</price>
            <stock_quantity>36</stock_quantity>
            <reorder_quantity>0</reorder_quantity>
            <height>0.000000</height>
            <length>0.000000</length>
            <diameter>0.000000</diameter>
            <weight>0.000000</weight>
            <color>Black</color>
            <material>Leather</material>
            <barcode>883045300164</barcode>
            <release_date>2008-11-10</release_date>
            <images>
                <image>/AL10sds0XO/sdsdsd.jpg</image>
                <image>/sdsds/AL1sd00XOB.jpg</image>
                <image>/AL1sdsds00XO/sdsds.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <categories>
                <category code="80" video="0" parent="44">sdgsdgsdg</category>
                <category code="181" video="0" parent="172">Sleep &amp; Lounge</category>
            </categories>
            <manufacturer code="AL" video="0">Allure sdsds</manufacturer>
            <type code="LI" video="0">sdsfsdfsd</type>
        </product>
EOT;
    $fo = fopen('test2.xml', 'wb');
    fwrite($fo, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
    fwrite($fo, "<products>\n");
    $sku = array('SKUTARGET', 'XXXXXXXX', 'SKUY12345', '124432XXK', 'FOO1234BAR');
    for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) { 
        shuffle($sku);
        fwrite($fo, str_replace('{{SKU}}', $sku[0], $xml));
    }
    fwrite($fo, "</products>\n");
    fclose($fo);
}
```

### Memory and Timing Function

```
function trial($method, $args) {
    //prime the pump
    if (!function_exists($method))
        throw BadFunctionCallException();

    call_user_func_array($method, $args);
    $iter = 2;
    $runtime = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i < $iter; $i++) {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $res = call_user_func_array($method, $args);
        $runtime += microtime(true)-$start;
    }
    return array(
        'peakmem' => memory_get_peak_usage(),
        'mem' => memory_get_usage(),
        'time' => $runtime/$iter,
        'return' => $res,
    );
}
function main($method, $filename) {
    $args = array($filename, 'SKUTARGET');
    $res = trial($method, $args);
    echo "Found products: ",count($res['return']),"\n";
    printf("%30s %3.2f %3.2f %4.3f\n", $method, $res['peakmem']/(1024*1024), $res['mem']/(1024*1024), $res['time']);
}

main($argv[1], $argv[2]);
```

### Regex vs XMLReader

Finally I tested these functions. The first two use the regexes suggested by other answers, and the third one uses `XMLReader`.

```
function getmatchingproducts_regex1($xmlfile, $desiredsku) {
    $pattern = "~<product [^<]*<sku>".preg_quote($desiredsku,'~')."</sku>.*?</product>~Sus";
    $xmlstr = file_get_contents($xmlfile);
    preg_match_all($pattern, $xmlstr, $matchingproducts);
    return $matchingproducts;
}

function getmatchingproducts_regex2($xmlfile, $desiredsku) {
    $pattern = "~<product [^<]*+<sku>".preg_quote($desiredsku,'~')."</sku>[^<]*(?:<(?!/product>)[^<]*)*</product>~Su";
    $xmlstr = file_get_contents($xmlfile);
    preg_match_all($pattern, $xmlstr, $matchingproducts);
    return $matchingproducts;
}

function getmatchingproducts_xml_expand($xmlfile, $desiredsku) {
    $r = new XMLReader();
    $r->open($xmlfile, null, LIBXML_COMPACT);
    $matchingproducts = array();
    do {
        // advance to first product element
        $r->read();
    } while ($r->nodeType!==XMLReader::NONE
        and !($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='product' and !$r->isEmptyElement));

    while ($r->nodeType!==XMLReader::NONE) {
        if ($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='product' and !$r->isEmptyElement) {
            $dom = $r->expand(new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8'));
            $sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
            if ((string) $sxe->sku===$desiredsku) {
                // Matching product found.
                // We have access to the <product> element and contents as:
                // * raw text via $r->readOuterXml()
                // * DOMDocument via $dom
                // * SimpleXML via $sxe
                // Pick the one you want and save:
                $matchingproducts[] = $r->readOuterXml();
                // null the rest to be very conservative about memory
                $dom = $sxe = null;
            }
        }
        // optimization--skip to next product sibling
        $r->next('product');
    }
    $r->close();
    return $matchingproducts;
}
```

Finally I saved all this in a file and ran it on my dual-core, 8GB system. (Numbers are peak memory, final memory, and seconds per iteration. "Found Products" is just to verify the correct number of products matched.)

```
$ php xmlreader.php getmatchingproducts_xml_expand test2.xml
Found products: 19969
getmatchingproducts_xml_expand 86.96 58.17 10.648
$ php xmlreader.php getmatchingproducts_regex1 test2.xml
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1253 bytes) in xmlreader.php on line 72
$ php xmlreader.php getmatchingproducts_regex2 test2.xml
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1253 bytes) in xmlreader.php on line 78
```

You'll notice that the regex methods could not even run without exhausting available memory! Further, the `XMLReader` methods (in addition to actually parsing XML correctly), used less memory than the size of the file. I'm willing to bet money that most of the `getmatchingproducts_xml_expand` memory is the `$matchedproducts` array, too, and not from parsing.  *You can cut down memory usage even further by wrapping the parser function in an class so you can retrieve one match at a time.*

The advantage of using a Regex, though, is that it's *much faster*. Here's another try, raising the memory limit to 1GB:

```
$ php -d memory_limit=1G xmlreader.php getmatchingproducts_regex1 test2.xml
Found products: 19968
    getmatchingproducts_regex1 181.31 30.01 1.421
$ php -d memory_limit=1G xmlreader.php getmatchingproducts_regex2 test2.xml
Found products: 19968
    getmatchingproducts_regex2 181.31 30.01 0.906
```

All of that speed comes from ignoring the rules of XML parsing and treating it as a string. (Interestingly, the fact that the whole file is in memory doesn't affect `XMLReader`'s speed, only its memory usage.)

If you need fast access *and* low memory usage, you need some kind of indexing or database. You can create a flat-file db using [sqlite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), [sqlite3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php), [dbm](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php) and load it with products keyed by SKU using `XMLReader`. Then instead of reading the XML file, load the xml string for that product from the db.

Just for kicks, I tried an `XMLReader` parsing method that didn't use expansion, to see if I could save time or memory. The difference was negligible, though, and the code much less clear.

```
function getmatchingproducts_xml_noexpand($xmlfile, $desiredsku) {
    $r = new XMLReader();
    $r->open($xmlfile, null, LIBXML_COMPACT);
    $matchingproducts = array();
    $candidateproduct = null;
    do {
        // advance to first product element
        $r->read();
    } while ($r->nodeType!==XMLReader::NONE
        and !($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='product' and !$r->isEmptyElement));
    while ($r->nodeType!==XMLReader::NONE) {
        if ($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='product' and !$r->isEmptyElement) {
            $candidateproduct = array($r->readOuterXML(), $r->depth);
            $r->read();
            while ($r->depth > $candidateproduct[1]) {
                if ($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='sku' and $r->readString()===$desiredsku) {
                    $matchingproducts[] = $candidateproduct[0];
                    $r->next('product');
                    break;
                } else {
                    $r->next();
                }
            }
            $candidateproduct = null;
        } else {
            $r->next();
        }
    }
    $r->close();
    return $matchingproducts;
}



$ php xmlreader.php getmatchingproducts_xml_noexpand test2.xml
Found products: 19969
getmatchingproducts_xml_noexpand 86.95 58.17 13.716
```

### Returning Parse Results Incrementally

Yet another implementation. This is probably as efficient as this can get. It parses the 120MB test file using less than 1MB of memory.

```
class ProductMatcher implements Iterator {
    // return values for next()
    const R_STR = 'product_str'; // return string
    const R_DOM = 'product_dom'; // return DOMDocument
    const R_SXE = 'product_sxe'; // return SimpleXMLElement

    protected $reader;
    protected $productcount = null;
    protected $product_str = null;
    protected $product_dom = null;
    protected $product_sxe = null;
    protected $xmlfile;
    protected $returnmethod;
    public $desiredsku;

    function __construct($xmlfile, $desiredsku, $returnmethod=self::R_STR) {
        $this->xmlfile = $xmlfile;
        $this->desiredsku = $desiredsku;
        $this->setReturnMethod($returnmethod);
    }
    function __destruct() {
        if (isset($this->reader)) {
            $this->reader->close();
        }
    }
    protected function _create() {
        $this->productcount = null;
        $this->reader = new XMLReader();
        $this->reader->open($this->xmlfile, null, LIBXML_COMPACT);
    }
    protected function _start() {
        $r =& $this->reader;
        do {
            // advance to first product element
            $r->read();
        } while ($r->nodeType!==XMLReader::NONE
            and !($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='product' and !$r->isEmptyElement));
    }
    protected function advance() {
        $r =& $this->reader;
        $productfound = false;
        $this->product_str = $this->product_sxe = $this->product_dom = null;
        while ($r->nodeType!==XMLReader::NONE and !$productfound) {
            if ($r->nodeType===XMLReader::ELEMENT and $r->name==='product' and !$r->isEmptyElement) {
                // xmlreader_print($r);
                $dom = $r->expand(new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8'));
                $sxe = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
                if ((string) $sxe->sku===$this->desiredsku) {
                    $this->product_str = $r->readOuterXml();
                    $this->product_sxe = $sxe;
                    $this->product_dom = $dom;
                    $productfound = true;
                    $this->productcount = (isset($this->productcount)) ? $this->productcount+1 : 0;
                }
            }
            // optimization--skip to next product sibling
            $r->next('product');
        }
        if (!$productfound) {
            $this->productcount = null;
        }
    }
    public function setReturnMethod($method) {
        $this->returnmethod = $method;
    }
    public function getReturnMethod() {
        return $this->returnmethod;
    }
    public function rewind() {
        $this->_create();
        $this->_start();
        $this->advance();
    }
    public function valid() {
        return $this->productcount!==null;
    }
    public function current() {
        return $this->{$this->returnmethod};
    }
    public function key() {
        return $this->productcount;
    }
    public function next() {
        $this->advance();
    }
}

function timeProductMatcher($filename) {
    $matcher = new ProductMatcher($filename, 'SKUTARGET');
    foreach ($matcher as $m) {}
    $runtime = 0;
    $iter = 2;
    for ($i=0; $i < $iter; $i++) { 
        $start = microtime(true);
        $matcher = new ProductMatcher($filename, 'SKUTARGET');
        foreach ($matcher as $n => $match) {}
        $runtime += microtime(true)-$start;
    }
    echo "Found products: ",$n+1, "\n";
    printf("%30s %3.2f %3.2f %4.3f\n", 'ProductMatcher', memory_get_peak_usage()/(1024*1024), memory_get_usage()/(1024*1024), $runtime/$iter);
}
timeProductMatcher($argv[1]);
```

Results:

```
$ php xmlreader.php test2.xml
Found products: 19969
                ProductMatcher 0.76 0.75 10.394
```

Expanded example usage:

```
$matcher = new ProductMatcher($filename, 'SKUTARGET', ProductMatcher::R_SXE);
foreach ($matcher as $product) {
    // $product is a SimpleXMLElement because we specified R_SXE
    (string) $product->sku === 'SKUTARGET'; // true
}
```

Comment: interesting on this would have never though phrasing a 100mb to pluck just one entry would cost only 1mb.. I'll try it out.  Thanks for the help I'll get back.  tk -J

Comment: I'm not sure why you think xml parsing can't be done with very little memory! There are many different kinds of incremental XML parsers.

Comment: @Francis Avila well at the moment cause it doesn't seem to be that fast.. I'm testing out the prosscess now.. but al first trys with all the different ways you can apporch this via google it just always seemed to do one of two things, cup intensive or memroy intensive.   I didn't know you could just basicly do what I was trying to do all with in the xml prasing proccess.  Testing stuff now.. I'll get back .. tk -J

Comment: It's not very fast because it's a flat unindexed XML file. That's why I suggested you put these entries in a database (even a key-value DBM store) of some kind if you need low memory usage *and* speed.

Comment: It **seems** that this works very well.. I am still testing but as of yet.. is there a better way to get to the value of a node?  This is how I'll get it now.
`$xml_str = new ProductMatcher($xml_source,$line[0]); 
     foreach ($xml_str as $xml) {
      $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
      $sku= $xml->xpath('.//sku');
      $mess.= $sku[0].":--ON sku<br/>";
}`

Comment: *By definition* the SKU of `$xml` will always be what you specified in the constructor! Also, you can change the data type of `$xml` to be `SimpleXMLElement` by default with the third constructor argument or `setReturnMethod()`. I feel like you're not reading the code very closely...

Comment: I added an example to the end of the answer.

Comment: Hello, so I have been testing the crap of this.. It works but it's 1 secound per and it's 30K of them.  what exectly are you suggesting here on the db end of things?  Is that really going to be faster to put it in the db and then pull it back out to process?  tk for the help

Comment: I'm suggesting you need some sort of indexing because you are essentially doing a linear search through a big xml file every time. Databases are great at indexing, so split up the big XML into individual product elements, load into a DB, create necessary indexes (e.g. SKU index), and then query the db instead of the big XML file. You can use a simple flat-file key-value store like [DBA](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dba.php) provides, or you can convert the XML record into a relational model and store in SQL, or even use a native XML database.

Comment: Hello, I'll try to see if I can get what your talking about up and running.  Just not 100% on this speeding things up lol.. tk

Comment: What I'm suggesting is the equivalent of putting each product element in its own file with the SKU as the filename. How could that *not* speed things up over what you are doing?

Comment: lol.. I have no idea.  I figured that breaking it up would speed it up but... well I haven't been seeing it.. so under your modle here.. um.. well I guess I'm just not seeing it.. what just basicly do what I started off with where I cut it in peices and save to a file then parse it?  Seems to be where you are headed here, back to where I started?

Comment: You need to expand a lot more (in another question) on what your larger goal is--all you have told us is "I have a giant XML file, and I want to retrieve a product element with a given SKU, quickly and without using much memory". If you have a read-heavy random-access load where you're repeatedly pulling out a product element based on SKU, then you need to split that giant XML file into its component product elements and index by SKU. The indexing is just as vital (maybe more vital) than the splitting. BTW, if this answer answered your question you should mark it so others can find it.

Comment: Question when you say an index, do you mean you can call a block by the node idex to speed this all up?

Comment: I just mean you need to turn all your linear searches into direct accesses. Right now if the product you want is the 10000th product in the document, you need to visit all previous 9999 products before you find it. If you had each product split up and indexed by SKU, you could have direct access to the product. if you really cannot grasp what I am saying you should present this problem in another question and mark an answer for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex to parse xml. Instead, use the family of [xml tools for php](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). It's not clear exactly what you want to do here. It looks like you want to pick out a specific element from the document and replace it with something else. Here is an [example](http://codepad.org/NxjOduX8).

[edit] Ok, so if you want to process large xml files, use [xmlreader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).

Comment: Sorry, I would down vote this for not even reading it but I can't.  I know all about how to phrase an xml file but like I said that is not an option here.  Got to remember that doing so is a memory intensive task. ;) tk for the try.

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC then why does your code above load all the xml into a string?

Comment: the reason is to do what the question is, ie: because the xml as a string cut and shorten then parsed should IIRC use less then phrasing and then getting would the block I need.  I don't have control over the orientating file, just the copy I make of it so turning the xml into an array or object right off is not able to be done, but cutting out the extra first then parsing the xml can be done.  If you can show me a way to parse the xml with less cost of a str being processed then I'm all ready to recant :D .

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to extract the matching `<product>..</product>` bit, use `preg_match`, not `preg_replace`.

```
$pattern = "~<product .*?<sku>$tar_sku</sku>.*?</product>~is";
$returnValues = preg_match($pat,$xml_str);
```

Here `$returnValues` is an array that is either empty or has one elment `$returnValues[0]` containing the relevant bit of XML you're after.

This is because `preg_match` stops at the first match. If you *know* that there'll only be one corresponding `SKUTARGET` in the whole XML, use `preg_match`. If you think there could be more than one and want to extract *all* of them, use `preg_match_all`.

The regex is basically the same as yours, except:

- you can't use `/` to delimit your regex (like `/regex/`) if there are internal `/` *within* the regex, unless you escape them. So you'd have to escape the `/` in `</sku>` etc. I've changed the delimiter to `~` so I don't need to bother escaping my internal `/`.
- `<product *` -> `<product .*` (the former only matches spaces)
- `</sku>*</product>` -> `</sku>.*?</product>` (the former only matches 0 or more `>` after the `/sku`.
- changed greedy `.*` to non-greedy `.*?` to prevent grabbing XML belonging to the next product, for example.

Comment: question is this tested? Sorry didn't get to test before I left for the day.  tk -J

Comment: You can always test it yourself, either with your page or (for example) [this online tester](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html). For what it's worth though, yes, this is tested (on your sample XML snippet).

Comment: rock on.. I'll test it tomorrow when I get back.  Sorry had to ask, most people spot and hope anwsers so it's nice to know if I'm just retesting.  Thanks.. cheers -Jeremy

Comment: Hello, I was able to get back to this now.. I tried yours and it didn't work for me.. It's posting in the edit above. tk -J

Comment: I tried this on the online tester I linked earlier (copy/pasted the XML & pattern) - I'm not sure why your code isn't working. is $returnValue[0] blank or something?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you're using `preg_match` incorrectly.  The return value is just an integer representing the number times the regex matched--i.e., `0` or `1`.  If you want to retrieve the matched text, you have to supply an array to store it in:

```
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

But there's a problem with the regex too, which you'll see if you make the *second* `<product>` element your target instead of the first one.  The match still starts with the first `<product>` element, then continues to the end of the second one.  The reluctant `.*?` is not sufficient to guarantee the shortest possible match, because it only affects where the match *ends*, not where it *starts*.

You need to make sure that, after it matches the opening `<product>` tag, it can't match any more `<product>` or `</product>` tags before it finds the `<sku>` tag.  Assuming `<sku>` is always first element listed inside the `<product>` element, that's a simple matter of changing the first `.*?` to `[^<]*`:

```
"~<product [^<]*<sku>$tar_sku</sku>.*?</product>~is"
```

Furthermore, given the size of the files, it might be worth the effort the make the regex as efficient as possible.  To that end, I would make that first quantifier possessive - `[^<]*+` - and replace the other `.*?` with something more deterministic.

```
"~<product [^<]*+<sku>$tar_sku</sku>[^<]*(?:<(?!/product>)[^<]*)*</product>~"
```

Notice that I also removed the modifiers; the `s` flag is irrelevant now since there are no dots in regex, and the `i` flag probably never was needed, given that XML tag names are case sensitive.  If the SKU isn't, you can apply the `i` flag to just that part of the regex with an inline modifier, i.e., `(?i:...)`:

```
"~<product [^<]*+<sku>(?i:$tar_sku)</sku>[^<]*(?:<(?!/product>)[^<]*)*</product>~"
```

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/mZqFz

Comment: Oh I did test this.. it does work to find the string and I have had a good run at it.  I'm testing out the other one and I'll benchmark both solutions.  Thanks -J